# Spark partition issue with Stanford NLP

Tags: apache-spark, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to process millions of data with spark/scala integrated with stanford NLP (3.4.1).
Since I am using social media data I have to use NLP for the themes generation (pos tagging) and Sentiment calculation.

I have to deal with Twitter data and NON Twitter data separately.So I have two classes that deal with Twitter/Non Twitter

I am using lasy val initialization from each class for loading the stanfordNLP

```
features: Seq[String] = Seq("tokenize","ssplit","pos","parse","sentiment")
  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("annotators", features.mkString(", "))
  props.put("pos.model", "tagger/gate-EN-twitter.model")
  props.put("parse.model", "tagger/englishSR.ser.gz");
  val pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
```

Note: For above Twitter I am using different pos model and shift reduce parse model for parsing. The reason I use shift reduce parser is for some of the junk
data at rum time the default PCFG model takes lot of time for processing and getting some Exception.Shift reduce parser will take around 15 seconds at load time and its faster at run time while processing the 
data.

NonTwitter class

```
 features: Seq[String] = Seq("tokenize","ssplit","pos","parse","sentiment")
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("annotators", features.mkString(", "))
    props.put("parse.model", "tagger/englishSR.ser.gz");
```

Here I am using the default pos model and shift reduce parser

Problem:

Currently we am running with 8 Nodes with 6 cores and I can run with 48 partition. For to process millions of data
with the above configuration with lesser partition it works fine for me.

8 Nodes and 6 cores we have almost 48 partition and if I ran with 42 Number of partition it takes around 1 hr to finish the processing.

with the current configuration I need to scale it to 200 partition

8 Nodes and 6 cores we have almost 48 partition and if we ran with 200 Number of partition it takes around 2 hr and finally throwing some exception saying the one node is lost
or java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: annotator "sentiment" requires annotator "binarized_trees" etc etc.

The problem is only if we scale up the number of partition to 200 with 8 Nodes and 6 cores which we have only 48 cores.

I have the suspect that its because of loading the shift reduce parser loading at each partition. I thought of loading this class at one time and then do the Broadcast but standforndNLP class is not searializable so I cannot broadcast.

The reason we need to scale to 200 partition is it will run quickly with lesser time to process this data.

Comment: have you tried passing NLP jar as part of submit-spark (or bundling it with your application)? Essentially additional jars should be shipped by scheduler to workers before it launches tasks in remote JVM

Comment: yes i am bundling with the application jars. but I can/t scale up the application with more number of partition

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the details of your message with apparently different results with different numbers of workers/partitions, but what you want to do is load the appropriate CoreNLP once on each worker. (And you can have two different CoreNLP pipelines loaded in one program.)

Have you tried the approach that Evan Sparks describes on this thread? http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-and-Stanford-CoreNLP-td19654.html

Comment: Thanks Christopher Manning. yes I am. when i tried with tokenize","ssplit","pos", there is no issues 200 partition is getting the output less than 30 minutes for almost a million data. i can see the output.But when i tried with tokenize","ssplit","pos","parse" and then set the  parse model props.put("parse.model", "tagger/englishSR.ser.gz"), i am getting this out of memory error. its running on 64 bit machine with XX:MaxPermSize=1024m and i tried with 2048 but no luck.thanks for looking into it